# Fetching JSON to ViewController and segue to 2nd ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, api, swift4.2

I have fetched and parsed my Data from API in JSON format to FirstViewController and want to segue to the SecondViewController with the data selected at the concrete person from FirstViewController. The Problem is that I have an API with such example URL: https://www.example.com/api/?action=**persons**&ln=en which gives me all persons in this format:

```
[
  {
    "p_id": "4107",
    "p_name": "Name1 Surname1",
    "p_role": "Role1",
    "general_image": "/imagedb/persons/4107/main/1.jpg"
  },{
    "p_id": "1978",
    "p_name": "Name2 Surname2",
    "p_role": "Role2",
    "general_image": "/imagedb/persons/1978/main/1.jpg"
  }, {...
...}
]
```

I am showing all these persons in my FirstViewController in CollectionView, which is working correctly, with images, names, roles. But also I need to show my SecondViewController with the data selected in FirstVC. My API for personByID is like this URL: https://www.example.com/api/?action=**person**&ln=en&personId=1978 which gives me JSON Data in this format:

```
{
"p_id": "1978",
"p_category": "[2]",
"p_name": "Name2 Surname2",
"p_role": "Role2",
"p_short": null,
"p_text": "long text...",
"p_date_start": "1922.02.05",
"p_date_end": "",
"p_profile_image": "1",
"p_status": "1",
"p_lang": "en",
"general_image": "/imagedb/persons/1978/main/1.jpg",
"photos": [
    {
        "image_id": "5",
        "p_id": "1978",
        "lang": "en",
        "text": "some text...",
        "general": "/imagedb/persons/1978/5.jpg",
        "thumbs": "/imagedb/persons/1978/thumb/5.jpg"
    },
    {
        "image_id": "7",
        "p_id": "1978",
        "lang": "en",
        "text": "some text...",
        "general": "/imagedb/persons/1978/7.jpg",
        "thumbs": "/imagedb/persons/1978/thumb/7.jpg"
    }
]
}
```

This is my Person Struct:

```
struct Person {
 let id: String
 let name: String
 let role: String
 fileprivate let imageURLString: String

 var imageURL: URL? {
    return URL(string: "https://www.example.com\(imageURLString)")
 }
}

 extension Person: JSONDecodable {
  init(_ decoder: JSONDecoder) throws {
     self.id = try decoder.value(forKey: "p_id")
     self.name = try decoder.value(forKey: "p_name")
     self.role = try decoder.value(forKey: "p_role")
     self.imageURLString = try decoder.value(forKey: "general_image")
 }
}
```

This is My FIRST VC:

```
import UIKit

class PersonListViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var personPages: [PagedResult<Person>] = [] {
    didSet {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadPersons()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    guard let selectedIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first else {
        return
    }
    collectionView.deselectItem(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: animated)
}

var service = ExampleWebService()
private func loadPersons(page: Int = 0, resultsPerPage: Int = 5) {
    service.persons(page: page, resultsPerPage: resultsPerPage) { (personPage) in
        guard !self.loadedPersonPageNumbers.contains(page) else { return }
        self.personPages.append(personPage)
        self.updateLastIndexPath(personPage)
    }
}

private(set) var lastIndexPath: IndexPath?
private func updateLastIndexPath(_ personPage: PagedResult<Person>) {
    if personPage.results.isEmpty {
        lastIndexPath = nil
    }
    else {
        lastIndexPath = calculateLastIndexPath()
    }
}

private func calculateLastIndexPath() -> IndexPath? {
    guard let lastPage = personPages.last else { return nil }
    let section = lastPage.pageNumber
    let row = lastPage.results.count - 1
    return IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
}

fileprivate var loadedPersonPageNumbers: [Int] {
    return personPages.map { $0.pageNumber }
}

func person(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Person? {
    guard indexPath.section < personPages.count else {
        return nil
    }
    guard indexPath.row < personPages[indexPath.section].results.count else {
        return nil
    }
    let page = personPages[indexPath.section]
    return page.results[indexPath.row]
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let personViewController = segue.destination as? PersonViewController,
        let selectedIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first else {
        return
    }
    personViewController.person = person(at: selectedIndexPath)
}

 @IBAction func exitToPersonsView(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

 }
}

extension PersonListViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
 fileprivate var nextPageIndex: Int {
    guard let lastPage = personPages.last else {
        return 0
    }

    return lastPage.pageNumber.advanced(by: 1)
 }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath == lastIndexPath {
        loadPersons(page: nextPageIndex)
    }
 }
}
extension PersonListViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    return personPages.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return personPages[section].results.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: PersonListCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PersonListCollectionViewCell

    cell.person = person(at: indexPath)

    return cell
}
}

extension PersonListViewController: UINavigationBarDelegate {
 func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
    return .topAttached
 }
}
```

And this is My Second VC:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

final class PersonViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imagesCollectionVIew: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var personRole: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var customNavigationBar: UINavigationBar!

var personImagesByID: [PagedResult<Person>] = [] {
    didSet {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.imagesCollectionVIew.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadPersonImagesByID()
}

var person: Person?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let person = person {
        title = person.name
        personRole.text = person.role
    }
    customNavigationBar.topItem?.title = title
}

var service = ExampleWebService()
private func loadPersonImagesByID(page: Int = 0, resultsperPge: Int = 5) {
    service.persons(page: page, resultsPerPage: resultsperPge) { (personPage) in
        guard !self.loadedPersonPageNumbers.contains(page) else {
            return
        }
        self.personImagesByID.append(personPage)
        self.updateLastIndexPath(personPage)
    }
}

private(set) var lastIndexPath: IndexPath?
private func updateLastIndexPath(_ personPage: PagedResult<Person>) {
    if personPage.results.isEmpty {
        lastIndexPath = nil
    }
    else {
        lastIndexPath = calculateLastIndexPath()
    }
}

private func calculateLastIndexPath() -> IndexPath? {
    guard let lastPage = personImagesByID.last else {
        return nil
    }
    let section = lastPage.pageNumber
    let item = lastPage.results.count - 1
    return IndexPath(row: item, section: section)
}

fileprivate var loadedPersonPageNumbers: [Int] {
    return personImagesByID.map { $0.pageNumber }
}

 func person(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Person? {
    guard indexPath.section < personImagesByID.count else {
        return nil
    }
    guard indexPath.item < personImagesByID[indexPath.section].results.count else {
        return nil
    }
    let page = personImagesByID[indexPath.section]
    return page.results[indexPath.item]
 }
}

extension PersonViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
 fileprivate var nextPageIndex: Int {
    guard let lastPage = personImagesByID.last else {
        return 0
    }
    return lastPage.pageNumber.advanced(by: 1)
 }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath == lastIndexPath {
        loadPersonImagesByID(page: nextPageIndex)
    }
 }
}

extension PersonViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: self.imagesCollectionVIew.frame.height - 17, height: self.imagesCollectionVIew.frame.height - 17)
 }
}

extension PersonViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
 func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return personImagesByID.count
 }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return personImagesByID[section].results.count
 }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: PersonViewCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImagesCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PersonViewCollectionViewCell

    cell.person = person(at: indexPath)

    return cell
 }
}

extension PersonViewController: UINavigationBarDelegate {
 func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
    return .topAttached
 }
}
```

Now my issue is that I am having a problem of how to write correctly my second struct PersonByID and when clicking on the person from First VC to show me data in Second VC from personByID URL Path.

Comment: There is too much information for people to be able to easily answer your question. I'm also not sure about what you are actually asking. If the data is different from both VCs you don't need to make them match, just pass the corresponding "p_id".

Comment: @Pochi Consider a library of famous persons. In first vc there are collectionview list of 100 persons. Each has its image, name and role. When tapping on for example Adam who is Composer, I need to bring the second vc where there is a biography of Adam and 5-10 his pictures on the bottom